# going from 2AWG wires down to 14AWG

Tags: power, connector, design, wiring, enclosure

So I basically have a 2 AWG power wire, but I want to end up with about 5 or 6 14AWG wires so I can put the power through a connector. Does anyone have methods of going from a 2AWG to multiple 14 AWG wires?

Comment: PCB edge mount connector? Solder the large cable to the PCB (or use solder terminal).

Comment: Sorry, its not on a PCB, its supposed to pigtail through a case

Comment: If it is stranded 2awg you could split open 12" of cable  and rebraid as a cat o nine tails from the strands see Ashley's book of knots.

Comment: 2 AWG means a section area of 33.6 mm2. 14 AWG has a section area of 2.08 mm2. You would need 17 wires to be able to put the same power through those wires, not 5 or 6. Unless that cable is severely over-engineered, that seems like a very bad idea. What is connected by that cable? How much power is going through it? What voltage?

Comment: Through a set of individual fuses (one per wire) might be a good idea.

Comment: @JasonNguyen was suggesting making a tiny PCB to solder to the cable to break out a connector.

Comment: @jcaron 85A, 2AWG because over specced

Comment: Question needs to define load, distance, stranded or solid and breakers or PTC, voltage, safety , environmental and budget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Insulated blocks (Polaris and MAC)

I would use a 3-void POLARIS style connector ($10-ish) to split out from 2 AWG to two 6 AWG, then two MAC Block connectors ($???) to adapt #6 to three #14 each.

All of these accept only 1 wire per void, except for the MAC Block, which allows 4 wires per void if they're #10 or smaller.

### Uninsulated blocks

Another way to solve this is to use "accessory ground bar kits" ($7-ish) intended for service panels.  These are readily available at your friendly neighborhood electrical supply, by which I mean Greybar, Platt, City Electric etc.  You shouldn't have any trouble finding one that has a large void for a #2 wire.  All the "normal sized" voids accept #14.

You'll be on your own to insulate these, however.

### Don't underestimate the voltage drop boogeyman, though

You can't just do a wire size bump and call it good.  You actually have to crunch the numbers.  I once saw a solar installation that was 15A and installed with #10 wire 75' to the 12V solar array. The person reasoned "#14 is good enough, and I'm doing *two* bumps! That oughta be plenty." In fact, *much* more was needed.  That solar system never worked properly, and the person got frustrated with solar and gave it up and paid for AC power service.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a note from marlinespike seamanship, with a stranded cable you can split and rebraid the ends like you would rope.

You can braid a cat 'o nine tails from one fat cable, and terminate each end at your connectors

[image]

Now for a professional product you can have such a cable made for you custom, but if you are working with large stranded wire you can take a note from this 19th century tradition and make it yourself.

Roughly, split the cable, extract the strands, Seperate into 10 bundles , rebraid and insulate, zip ties above and below the joint for rigidity. The final cable may need to be derated relative to standard 2awg .

Comment: Whipped that up pretty quick.